# CodeWarrior compiler warning: "Possible loss of data"

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, microcontroller, codewarrior, analog-digital-converter

Please consider the following code:

```
unsigned int  beta;

unsigned int theta;

unsigned int m = 4;

unsigned int c = 986;

unsigned int Rpre = 49900;



unsigned int getUAnalog(unsigned char channel) // to get the PT1000 Signal

{

unsigned int result;

unsigned int f_temp;

//select channel and initiate conversion

ADCSC1 |= (channel & 0b11111);



//wait until conversion is complete

while(!ADCSC1_COCO);



f_temp = ADCRH;

f_temp <<= 8;

f_temp += ADCRL;



beta = (((f_temp) / (4096*28))*1000); // warning: possible loss of data.

theta = ((((beta)*(Rpre))/(1-beta))*1000);

result = (theta-c)/(m);

return result;
}
```

I am using MC9S08DZ60 (http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/data_sheet/MC9S08DZ60.pdf) with PT1000-Temperature Sensor on CodeWarrior version 5.9.0 . This function is meant to calculate the temp and return "result". But the "beta" and "theta" values remain 0. No Change.

Also i get the warning as C2705: Possible Loss of Data.  The value of "result" is not right. PLease help as i dont have clue of what going wrong!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `sizeof(unsigned int)` on your platform?  `4096*28` will overflow a 16-bit uint.

Comment: @simonc: 65535. ANd i have no option of using float.

Comment: @sheetansh what about a long?

Comment: @sheetansh You could use `long int` or `long long` instead.

Comment: @h4lc0n: already tried the same, no change with the o/p.

Comment: @simonc: tried the same, also tried to use typecasting, no change!

Comment: f_temp / (4096*28) will most probably always give 0 as it's not a floating point operation. Unless f_temp is greater or equal to (4096*28), you always get 0, is this intended behavior?

Comment: @h4lc0n: the value of f_temp is always less than (4096*28). actually the max value that f_temp can get from ADC is 4096 (the adc is configured for 12bits operation)
Is there a way of using bitshift operators to do such calculations? 
would the result still be the same?

Answer (score 3):

Your `4096*28` doesn't fit into a 16-bit unsigned integer and is going to be truncated, giving you wrong results and that's why you got the warning.

But most importantly...

This

```
beta = (((f_temp) / (4096*28))*1000); // warning: possible loss of data.

theta = ((((beta)*(Rpre))/(1-beta))*1000);

result = (theta-c)/(m);
```

is equivalent to

```
beta = (((f_temp) / (4096*28))*1000);

theta = ((((beta)*(49900))/(1-beta))*1000);

result = (theta-986)/(4);
```

which in turn is equivalent to:

```
result = ((((((((f_temp) / (4096*28))*1000))*(49900))/(1-(((f_temp) / (4096*28))*1000)))*1000)-986)/(4)
```

If you [plot it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28x%29+%2F+%284096%2a28%29%29%2a1000%29%29%2a%2849900%29%29%2F%281-%28%28%28x%29+%2F+%284096%2a28%29%29%2a1000%29%29%29%2a1000%29-986%29%2F%284%29), you'll see there's a [discontinuity at `f_temp` = 14336/125 ≈ 115](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-x%2a125%2F14336) and [the range of `result` is from -986/4 (≈-247) at `f_temp`=0 to ≈-4*10<sup>9</sup> at `f_temp`=115 or -∞ at `f_temp`=14336/125](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28%28%28%28%28%28%28%28x%29+%2F+%284096%2a28%29%29%2a1000%29%29%2a%2849900%29%29%2F%281-%28%28%28x%29+%2F+%284096%2a28%29%29%2a1000%29%29%29%2a1000%29-986%29%2F%284%29%2C+0+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+65535).

This suggests that either you're doing something wrong (you've got wrong formulas or constants) or you aren't giving us enough information (the valid range(s) of `f_temp` would be nice to have). And using integer arithmetic for these calculations is going to be problematic due to the ranges of `result`.

Comment: OK! this is wat i am trying to do.

Comment: ADC is configured for 12 bit operation. the output i get is analog to digital conversion of the sensor signal. then using the equation derived from the op-amp circuit i get the equations for beta(beta=Nadc/((2^12)*gain);and theta (theta = (beta*Rpre)/(1-beta) ).So the theta is the resistence value of the sensor. Now pt1000 is a linear temperature sensor therefore y=m*x+c is applied.  the value of m and c have been obtained from solving the equation for standard values.

Comment: Nadc is the actual value i get from the sensor.